# Winston : How to get logging with timestamp at the front

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

How do configure Winston to output log like

2019-06-30 17:39:07 : error : Cheese has rotten

I tried this but it is outputting timestamp at the end

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),
        winston.format.simple()
    )
});
```

error: Cheese has rotten! {"timestamp":"2019-06-30 23:32:02"}

Comment: i think you need to have a custom format, in winston, you can mention custom format

Answer (score 2):

try the below code. I hope this will solve the issue. You can customize in your own required way in myFormat custom function

```
const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {
  return `${timestamp} : [${label}] : ${level}: ${message}`;
});

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    label({ label: 'right meow!' }),
    timestamp(),
    myFormat
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()]
});
```